# Set aperture in 3D plot in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d

I know that `view_init()` allows the user to set elevation and azimuth in a 3D plot, but What happend with the aperture? Is there any command that allows the user to set an aperture so the plot looks like it was a 2D plot when elev=0 and azimuth=0? 
This way I could get a figure of the 3D plot with a specific camara view point and then set elevation and azimuth to 0 and get the 2D side view of the same data.

Comment: Something like an [orthographic projection](https://codeyarns.com/2014/11/13/how-to-get-orthographic-projection-in-3d-plot-of-matplotlib/)?

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. It perfectly worked in my code